# why does <?php echo date("m/d/Y" strtotime('second wednesday June 2016')) ?> output 6/15/2016 instead of 6/8/2016?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

why does

```
<?php echo date("m/d/Y" strtotime('second Wednesday June-2016')) ?>
```

output 6/15/2016 instead of 6/8/2016?

This is the work around I've come up with --- not very eloquent:

```
    <?php
    months = array( 1=>'Jan',2=>'Feb',3=>'Mar',4=>'Apr',5=>'May',6=>'Jun',7=>'Jul',8=>'Aug',9=>'Sep',10=>'Oct',11=>'Nov',12=>'Dec');
   $year = "2016";
    $month = "06";
    $smonth=$months[(int)$month];
    $tstr=$month."/01/".$year;
    $dow=date("D",strtotime($tstr));
    if ( $dow == "Wed" ) {
        $nstr="first";
    } else {
        $nstr="Second";
    }
    $edate= date("m/d/Y", strtotime($nstr.' Wednesday '.$smonth.'-'.$year));
    echo $edate."<br>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Instead of `second` try using `2`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for relative date formats:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

It looks like they all use the word "of" between the month and day. I tried it on my local server with `echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime('second Wednesday of June-2016'));` and it worked. It looks like leaving out the "of" causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the following:

```
<?php echo date("m/d/Y" strtotime('second Wednesday June-2016')) ?>
```

The two problems with it are that there should be a comma after `"m/d/Y"`, although I assume that this typo was only on Stackoverflow. The other problem is that it should say `strtotime('second Wednesday of June 2016')`

Leaving out the word `of` can cause unknown results.